# How to remove element using splice?

Tags: javascript

I am not able to pass this test.

The result is `undefined`.

How do I solve the problem?

Code:

```
mocha.setup('bdd');
var expect = chai.expect;

function removeEnd(arr, n) {
/*
    write a program remove n element last of an array
*/
var removedItems= arr.splice(arr.length-n, n);

}

console.log(removeEnd([2, 3, 1, 8, 9, 7], 3));

describe('removeEnd', () => {
  it('Remove n elements from the endof an given array', () => {
    expect(removeEnd([2, 3, 1, 8, 9, 7], 3)).to.eql([2, 3, 1]);
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

Comment: Your code is removing the elements properly, but the test requires the function to return the changed array (kind of a weird test IMO, since `splice` mutates)

Comment: Your function doesn't contain a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `slice()`, not `splice()`:

```
function removeEnd(arr, n) {
    return arr.slice(0, arr.length - n);
}
```

Comment: OMG. thank you so much for your support. i I have finished. ^^

Comment: Hi @Atsh - if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.